# Using TypeScript types from JS

Tags: javascript, typescript, jsdoc

I've enabled *checkJS* and *allowJS* in Typescript and created a simple fooInterface.d.ts file:

```
declare interface FooInterface {
  x();
}
```

I'm trying to typecheck a JS file against this interface:

```
/**
 * @implements {FooInterface}
 */
class Bar {
  y() {}
}
```

However I can't get it to throw an error upon running `tsc`.

Also tried simply writing `declare class`, didn't work either.

How can I reuse types from .d.ts files in JSDoc+JS?

Comment: I don't think that `@implements` works yet but there's an issue tracking it. Try `@extends`

Comment: Where can I find the issue? I tried to search for this in the issue tracker with no results. `@type + declare class` didn't work, `@extends + declare class` didn't work :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Supporting the JSDoc `@implements` tag has been requested in TypeScript and is tracked by https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/17498

The `@extends` tag will be supported in the next release of TypeScript (2.7) and is already available in the nightly builds (typescript@next) which, I might add, are remarkably stable.

You can get the nightly build with your package manager of choice. For example

using npm

```
$ npm install typescript@next
```

using jspm

```
$ jspm install typescript@next
```

using yarn

```
$ yarn add typescript@next
```